# SFML2, CMake and CLion, app crash

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sfml, clion

I'm trying to run my project using CLion, SFML2 and CMake. I also placed the .dll in the executable directory.
The lib is located into my project folder.

**CMakeLists.txt** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(c__)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.3.2/cmake/Modules/" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

set(SFML_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.3.2/lib")
set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.3.2/include")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window network audio system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use mingw x86_x64 and SFML2 64bits.
My app compiles but crash on start.
How can I fix that ?

Comment: "crash on start": What error does it show

Comment: make sure you don't mix debug and release modes/binaries

Comment: Process finished with status code : 0xC0000374. That's all i got